# Wordpress: not displaying all items in custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

Dear PHP / Wordpress / Dev Experts,

Ive build a plugin, with a custom post type and some advanced custom fields. The main goal is to list the members in my band, with pictures and name.

You can see it here: http://www.lucky13.nl/test/

I've managed to get everything working to my taste, however.. I have 5 bandmembers in my band which i've added, but i'm only seeing 4. Where is the 5th entry / post? I find that the first added bandmember is not displaying.

I assume this has to do with the loop, and the array not listing all items? But i'll leave this to the experts.. I would appreciate any comments of help!

My code:

```
<?php
    /*
    Plugin Name: VrolijkWebdesign - Bandmembers
    Description: For a bandwebsite to show bandmembers. 
    */
    /* Start Adding Functions Below this Line */
      

    /* NAME FUNCTION  */  
    function new_section_1(){
      
      $bandmembers = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'bandmembers'
      ));
      
      while($bandmembers->have_posts()) : $bandmembers->the_post(); 

      if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ):
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
    <!-- START HTML  -->

    <div class="span2">
    <figure class="snip1104">
      <img src="<?php echo $image[0] ;?>" alt='sample33'/>
      <figcaption>
        <h5> <?php the_field('firstname'); ?> <span> <?php the_field('lastname'); ?>
         </span></h5>
      </figcaption>
      <a href="#"></a>
    </figure>
    </div>
    <!-- END HTML -->
    <?php endif;
          endwhile;
    } 
     
    add_shortcode('band', 'new_section_1'); 
    ?>
```

Comment: you should add `'status' => 'publish'` otherwise posts in draft would show up and `'post_per_page' => -1`

Comment: Thanks a million Mark, this solved my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$bandmembers = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'bandmembers',
    'posts_per_page' => '5'
  ));
```

Try setting the `posts_per_page` argument. Since the default might be set to '4' by other filters.

If you want to get all posts in a single query use '-1' instead of '5'

You could also try the below for debugging purposes only:

-Try to set `post_status` to 'any' to make sure that post statuses are not a problem.

-Try `var_dump($bandmembers)` after doing the query to see the fetched posts before the loop starts.

Comment: default is same as setting in WordPress back-end, default 10

Comment: I would still give it a try to make sure no other filter is overriding your default value.  You could also try to set `post_status` to `any` to make sure that post statuses are not a problem.  One other thing you could do is `var_dump($bandmembers)` after doing the query to see the fetched posts before the loop starts.

Comment: Still getting only 4 posts? How many posts have been returned according tp the var_dump?

Comment: Thanks a million Omar, this solved my issue!

'posts_per_page' => '-1' sorted everything out. Looks like it was indeed overwritten by something else. Not quite sure by what, but i'm glad this solved it. Took me a whole day to figure it out! 

Thanks again!!